# NSDictionary query returning "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm setting up the following function in my iOS app:

```
    - (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {
        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"'%@'", result);

                                        NSData *returnedJSONData = result;

                                            NSError *jsonerror = nil;

                                            NSDictionary *categoryData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                                          JSONObjectWithData:returnedJSONData
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          error:&jsonerror];

                                            NSArray *resultArray = [categoryData objectForKey:@"results"];

                                            NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:1];
                                            NSNumber *numberOfTopCategories = [dictionary1 objectForKey:@"Number of top categories"];

//                                            NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:2];
//                                            NSNumber *topCategories = [dictionary2 objectForKey:@"Top categories"];

                                            NSDictionary *dictionary3 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:3];
                                            NSNumber *numberOfMatches = [dictionary3 objectForKey:@"Number of matches"];

//                                            NSDictionary *dictionary4 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:4];
//                                            NSNumber *userCategoriesThatMatchSearch = [dictionary4 objectForKey:@"User categories that match search"];


                                        if (!error) {


                                            // if 1 match found clear categoryResults and top2 array
                                            if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 1 ){
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue" sender:self];
                                            }

                                            // if 2 matches found
                                            else if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 2){
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowUserCategoryChooserSegue" sender:self];
                                                //default to selected categories criteria  -> send to matchcenter -> clear categoryResults and top2 array
                                            }

                                            // if no matches found, and 1 top category is returned
                                            else if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 0 && [numberOfTopCategories intValue] == 1) {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowCriteriaSegue" sender:self];
                                            }
                                            // if no matches are found, and 2 top categories are returned
                                            else if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 0 && [numberOfTopCategories intValue] == 2) {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSearchCategoryChooserSegue" sender:self];
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }];
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is decide which segue to take, depending on the key/value pairs of the JSON being returned. However, when the nextButton is pressed, my app crashes, and the following is returned:

```
2014-05-02 14:51:18.623 Parse+Storyboard[1325:60b] '{
    results =     (
                {
            "Number of top categories" = 2;
        },
                {
            "Top categories" =             (
                20349,
                9355
            );
        },
                {
            "Number of matches" = 0;
        },
                {
            "User categories that match search" =             (
            );
        }
    );
}'
2014-05-02 14:51:18.624 Parse+Storyboard[1325:60b] -[__NSDictionaryM bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa9d090
2014-05-02 14:51:18.639 Parse+Storyboard[1325:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa9d090'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02a771e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x026358e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b14243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02a6750b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02a670ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Foundation                          0x0237b4bc -[_NSJSONReader findEncodingFromData:withBOMSkipLength:] + 36
    6   Foundation                          0x0237b66b -[_NSJSONReader parseData:options:] + 63
    7   Foundation                          0x0237bc30 +[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:] + 161
    8   Parse+Storyboard                    0x000039ab __35-[SearchViewController nextButton:]_block_invoke + 203
    9   Parse+Storyboard                    0x0007b217 __40-[PFTask thenCallBackOnMainThreadAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 241
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x036877b8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0369c4d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0368a726 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02adc43e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02a1d5cb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02a1c9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x02a1c7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x02cd45ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x02cd442b GSEventRun + 104
    19  UIKit                               0x012f5f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    20  Parse+Storyboard                    0x00002fbd main + 141
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x038d1701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I can't seem to figure out which selector it's referring to, and why it's unrecognized.

Comment: "I can't seem to figure out which selector it's referring to" Why couldn't you have simply stepped through the code, line by line, in Xcode and see what line makes the error appears???

Comment: If you look at the error, the unrecognized selector is `bytes` sent to an NSMutableDictionary. According to the stack trace, this message is being sent from `+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:]`. Which brings us to [Martin R's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23435734/50742).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message

```
 -[__NSDictionaryM bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...
```

and the `NSLog()` output

```
'{ 
   ...
}'
```

one can see that the `result`
is not a string (containing JSON data), but a `NSDictionary`. So there is no need
to use `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                   withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                            block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

        NSArray *resultArray = [result objectForKey:@"results"];
        // ...
}];
```

Note also that the first array in an array has index *zero*, so you probably want
to retrieve the objects with index `0 .. 3` from `resultArray` instead of `1 .. 4`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign `NSString` directly to `NSData` like:

```
NSData *returnedJSONData = result;
```

Change that to:

```
NSData *returnedJSONData = [result dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

According to [callFunctionInBackground:withParameters:block:](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFCloud.html#//api/name/callFunctionInBackground%3awithParameters%3ablock%3a) documentation the type of result is id.

So from your crash log and this error message `-[__NSDictionaryM bytes]:`
I suspect that you are getting `NSDictionary` as response.

So change your method like:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch" withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text} block:^(NSDictionary *categoryData, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"'%@'", categoryData);
        NSArray *resultArray = [categoryData objectForKey:@"results"];
        NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSNumber *numberOfTopCategories = [dictionary1 objectForKey:@"Number of top categories"];


        NSDictionary *dictionary3 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:3];
        NSNumber *numberOfMatches = [dictionary3 objectForKey:@"Number of matches"];
        if (!error)
        {
              // if 1 match found clear categoryResults and top2 array
              if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 1 )
              {
                   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue" sender:self];
              }
              // if 2 matches found
              else if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 2)
              {
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowUserCategoryChooserSegue" sender:self];
                     //default to selected categories criteria  -> send to matchcenter -> clear categoryResults and top2 array
              }
              // if no matches found, and 1 top category is returned
              else if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 0 && [numberOfTopCategories intValue] == 1)
              {
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowCriteriaSegue" sender:self];
              }
              // if no matches are found, and 2 top categories are returned
              else if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 0 && [numberOfTopCategories intValue] == 2)
              {
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSearchCategoryChooserSegue" sender:self];
              }

        }
}];
```

Comment: I was getting a warning about that, so I thought that might be it. Making that change returns this though: http://codeshare.io/WTdCc

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, but my first portion of answer is regarding the String to data conversion. If you think my answer duplicates your answer and if you want me to delete my answer, I'll do it

Comment: @MidhunMP: My last comment was actually bad style and I apologize for that. I have deleted it.

Comment: @MartinR: It's Okay martin. It happens :) Sorry, if I hurt you in any path